# Empty Dynamic web project facet problem in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Im trying to make sample Dynamic web project on eclipse Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0).

the project build and run correctly but im getting this error in marker :

"**Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet.Unknown   Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)**"
[image]

Also im using JDK16. Things ive done to resolve the problem without any hope till now:

1-changing project java version in project facet :

[image]

2- installing java version 11 and change the %JAVA_HOME% in environment variable.

3- change the installed jre location in eclipse :

[image]

Comment: You have to configure the installed Java in the preferences in _Java > Installed JREs_ to be able to use it.

Comment: Did you use Java 11 also in your project? Please note, Eclipse 2021-03 has not yet built-in support for Java 16 since Java 16 was just released in March.

Comment: After Switching to JDK11 in  (preferences > Java > Installed JREs) and Project Java Path , Im getting this error now :
The project was not built due to "release 15 is not found in the system". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsisten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @howlger suggestion , by changing the default java version in Project facet to 15 , the error disappeared :
[image]